# Number of Jordan canonical form of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let, $A\in M(3,C)$. Assume that the characteristic & minimal polynomial of $A$ are known. Then what is the number of possible Jordan form of $A$ and how?

What changes if we replace $C$ by $R$ or if we replace 3 by 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** whether it's 3 or 4 will affect your answer, the choice of R vs. C will not.

Note that the degree of a factor in the characteristic polynomial is the multiplicity of the corresponding eigenvalue. That is, the degree is the sum of the sizes of the blocks associated with that eigenvalue.

The degree of a factor in the minimal polynomial is the size of the **largest** associated Jordan block.

An example for the $4 \times 4$ case:
$$
\pmatrix
{
1&1\\
&1\\
&&1&1\\
&&&1
}, \quad
\pmatrix
{
1&1\\
&1\\
&&1\\
&&&1
}
$$

Comment: So, for any matrix of order 3 the Jordan canonical form is unique but for order $n(\gt 3)$ it is not unique whether about the matrix we only know the characteristic & minimal polynomial. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, this is true.  Are you able to show why this is the case?

Comment: Yes...Yes...now it is clear to me...........

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
$$
{ 3 \choose 1}+{ 3 \choose 2}+{ 3 \choose 3}
$$

Comment: I don't understand anything.....